# Forwarding a US phone number (verizon iPhone) to an iPhone with EU SIM card

Tags: iphone, wifi, sim

I plan on traveling in Europe and getting a local SIM card, and placing it into my unlocked iPhone 13. I presume that will give me a local phone number. Is there a way to get calls to my US phone number to ring my EU-based phone with the local SIM card?

I'm fine with this happening via the phone network, via an app, or FaceTime, or some other mechanism. The iPhone will usually be on WiFi while in the EU (in addition to the local SIM card/phone network). I'm ok with missing forwarded calls while the phone is not on WiFI (if relevant).

Answer (score 1):

You could just set up forwarding directly but  you would be paying international Verizon rates for the forwarded calls even when on wifi.
You could transfer the number to Google voice and run the Google voice app on your phone along with Google hangouts. And then transfer the number back to Verizon when you get back. it’s 20 bucks to transfer the number to Google voice and I think it’s free to switch it back, and the incoming calls would be free.  Need more detail? Which option interests you?

Comment: Good points but I absolutely wouldn’t hassle with porting the number. I should write up a different answer to cover loading a new SIM and just using WiFi calling to get voicemail and calls from the domestic USA carrier and not messing with forwarding or porting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re OK missing calls when not on WiFi, I would not mess with swapping SIM and just toggle off cellular data and services in the main SIM and set up a dual SIM for Europe when you land.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209044

There are excellent apps to give you help with shopping, purchase, installation and FAQ on setting up your phone correctly. Friends and family have been very positive in their reviews of this one app for Americans traveling to Europe.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/airalo-esim-travel-internet/id1475911720